# Cannot export Deeplab model into Frozen graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have trained my own segmentation model using Deeplab and Mobilenet to segment squares from images. I want to export this model to a frozen graph. However, when I run `exported_model.py` script,  I am getting error:

```py
File is too short to be an sstable
```

Training and valuation scripts used:

```
NUM_ITERATIONS=5000
CKPT_NAME="deeplabv3_mnv2_pascal_train_aug"
CKPT_PATH="${TRAIN_LOGDIR}/model.ckpt-${NUM_ITERATIONS}"
EXPORT_PATH="${EXPORT_DIR}/frozen_inference_graph.pb"

=== Train the network ===
python "${WORK_DIR}"/train.py
--logtostderr
--train_split="train"
--model_variant="mobilenet_v2"
--output_stride=16
--train_crop_size=513
--train_crop_size=513
--train_batch_size=4
--training_number_of_steps="${NUM_ITERATIONS}"
--dataset="testset"
--tf_initial_checkpoint="${INIT_FOLDER}/${CKPT_NAME}/model.ckpt-30000.index"
--train_logdir="${TRAIN_LOGDIR}"
--dataset_dir="${FINAL_DATASET}"
--initialize_last_layer=False
--last_layers_contain_logits_only=False
--fine_tune_batch_norm=False

=== Run evaluation ===
python "${WORK_DIR}"/eval.py
--logtostderr
--eval_split="val"
--model_variant="mobilenet_v2"
--eval_crop_size=513
--eval_crop_size=513
--dataset="testset"
--checkpoint_dir="${TRAIN_LOGDIR}"
--eval_logdir="${EVAL_LOGDIR}"
--dataset_dir="${FINAL_DATASET}"
--max_number_of_evaluations=1

=== Visualize the results ===
python "${WORK_DIR}"/vis.py
--logtostderr
--vis_split="val"
--model_variant="mobilenet_v2"
--vis_crop_size=513
--vis_crop_size=513
--dataset="testset"
--checkpoint_dir="${TRAIN_LOGDIR}"
--vis_logdir="${VIS_LOGDIR}"
--dataset_dir="${FINAL_DATASET}"
--max_number_of_iterations=1
```

Everything is fine and dandy and I am able to visualize my results using above scripts. But when I have to create a frozen inference graph using export_model.py I get into trouble as follows : I run this script

```
python "${WORK_DIR}"/export_model.py
--logtostderr
--checkpoint_path="${CKPT_PATH}"
--export_path="${EXPORT_PATH}"
--model_variant="mobilenet_v2"
--num_classes=3
--crop_size=513
--crop_size=513
--inference_scales=1.0
```

I get the following error:

```py
INFO:tensorflow:Prepare to export model to: deeplab/exported_model/frozen_inference_graph.pb INFO:tensorflow:Exported model performs single-scale inference. WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/ajinkya/models/research/deeplab/core/feature_extractor.py:196: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use tf.cast instead. WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Colocations handled automatically by placer. WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py:127: checkpoint_exists (from tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use standard file APIs to check for files with this prefix. INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from deeplab/exp2/model.ckpt-4000 Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1334, in _do_call return fn(*args) File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1319, in _run_fn options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata) File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1407, in _call_tf_sessionrun run_metadata) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: file is too short to be an sstable [[{{node save/RestoreV2}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "deeplab/export_model.py", line 176, in tf.app.run() File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv)) File "deeplab/export_model.py", line 167, in main initializer_nodes=None) File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 151, in freeze_graph_with_def_protos saver.restore(sess, input_checkpoint) File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1282, in restore {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path}) File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in run run_metadata_ptr) File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1152, in _run feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata) File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1328, in _do_run run_metadata) File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1348, in _do_call raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: file is too short to be an sstable [[node save/RestoreV2 (defined at deeplab/export_model.py:153) ]]

Caused by op 'save/RestoreV2', defined at: File "deeplab/export_model.py", line 176, in tf.app.run() File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv)) File "deeplab/export_model.py", line 153, in main saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.model_variables()) File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 839, in init self.build() File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 851, in build self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True) File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 887, in _build build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore) File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 520, in _build_internal restore_sequentially, reshape) File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 338, in _AddRestoreOps restore_sequentially) File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 587, in bulk_restore return io_ops.restore_v2(filename_tensor, names, slices, dtypes) File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 1572, in restore_v2 name=name) File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper op_def=op_def) File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3300, in create_op op_def=op_def) File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1801, in init self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

DataLossError (see above for traceback): file is too short to be an sstable [[node save/RestoreV2 (defined at deeplab/export_model.py:153) ]]
```

How do I export the model into a frozen graph by removing this error ?

Comment: Please post all error log.